# JQuery add pagebreak (like Google Docs or MS Word) and go to next page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, tinymce

Hi i need to create function to add pagebreaks like Ms Word with header and footer:

This is my code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var page = function({
        $("*").before(<div id="header" style="border-bottom:2px solid;position:absolute; top:10px"></div>)
        $("*").after(<div id="footer" style="border-top:2px solid;position:absolute; bottom:10px"></div>);
        if ($(body).outerheight()) > 
        {
            $("#footer").after<div style="page-break-after:always, margin:9px solid;"></DIV>
        }   
    });
});
</script>
```

My problem is : How can I go to the next page(and create this) like google docs(space into page1 page 2)

I want to use this in tinymce 4.0.

Comment: Man .. you should re organize your code ASAP. clean things up.. you can use "`" AS WELL

Comment: `if ($(body).outerheight()) > ` this is a syntax error and so is the stuff just below that in `.after`(bad from here on) OK, and above that also - pretty much all syntax errors?

Comment: Please use code blocks in your question.

Comment: I need a corect code, this is my problem, i have some issues with jquery.I want to create that effect to got to the next page .but i haven't knowlege about this.please help me, is urgently:( and sorry for my poor english

Answer (score 0):

> Checks if the element with the class "height block" fits in a height
>   1000px, if it does not fit inserts a page break in the last line,
>   means that all the pages have 100px in height, every time it verifies
>   if the content fits in a 100px high page

My idea is to do something like google docs or Word in the page break, but for now it comes out even 1.0 version :P.

```js
var count_add_class = 1,
    tamanho_do_elemento = 1,
    count_soma = 0,
    i = 1;

$(".altura_bloco").each(function() {
    var a = count_add_class++;
    // pega a posição do elemento, e adcinando uma classe 1,2,3,4,5,6,7...
    $(this).addClass("element_height_" + a);

    tamanho_do_elemento = $(this).outerHeight();
    count_soma += tamanho_do_elemento;
    // console.log(tamanho_do_elemento);
    console.log(tamanho_do_elemento);

    if (count_soma > 937) {
        $(this).addClass("page-break");
        count_soma = tamanho_do_elemento;
        i++;
        // console.log(tamanho_do_elemento);
    }
});
```

```css
.altura_bloco {
   width: 400px;
   height: 400px;
   background: #000;
   margin: 10px;
 }
@media print {
  .page-break {
  display: block;
  page-break-before: always;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="altura_bloco"><br></div>
<div class="altura_bloco"><br></div>
<div class="altura_bloco"><br></div>
<div class="altura_bloco"><br></div>
<div class="altura_bloco"><br></div>
<div class="altura_bloco"><br></div>
<div class="altura_bloco"><br></div>
<div class="altura_bloco"><br></div>
<div class="altura_bloco"><br></div>
<div class="altura_bloco"><br></div>
<div class="altura_bloco"><br></div>
<div class="altura_bloco"><br></div>
<div class="altura_bloco"><br></div>
<div class="altura_bloco"><br></div>
<div class="altura_bloco"><br></div>
<div class="altura_bloco"><br></div>
<div class="altura_bloco" style="height: 500px"><br></div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: please add some description explaining answer to help other.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot. :D